# How To Encode A String To REG_BINARY With Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a value to a REG_BINARY using Powershell.  I can write to the REG_BINARY if I provide the data, but I need to be able to encode what I want to write in the file so I can use system and date variables.  Below is my code and error.

If you uncomment the first $data it will work.

```
function Convert-ToCHexString 
{
    param ([String] $str) 
    $ans = ''
    [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($str) | % { $ans += "0x{0:x2}," -f $_ }
    return $ans.Trim(' ',',')
}

$Folder = Convert-ToCHexString Z:\
$Username = Convert-ToCHexString $env:USERNAME
$Filename = Convert-ToCHexString \archive.pst

$key = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\0a0d020000000000c000000000000046"

#$data = 0x5a,0x3a,0x5c,0x61,0x72,0x63,0x68,0x69,0x76,0x65,0x2e,0x70,0x73,0x74
$data = $Folder + "," + $Username + "," + $Filename + ",0x00,0x00,0x00"

Set-ItemProperty -path $key -name "001f0324" -value ([byte[]]($data))
```

Below is the error I get:

Cannot convert value "0x5a,0x3a,0x5c,0x6a,0x62,0x79,0x65,0x72,0x73,0x5c,0x61,0x72,0x63,0x68,0x69,0x76,0x65,0x2e,0x70,0x73,0x74,0x00,0x00,0x00" to type"System.Byte[]". Error: "Cannot convert value "0x5a,0x3a,0x5c,0x6a,0x62,0x79,0x65,0x72,0x73,0x5c,0x61,0x72,0x63,0x68,0x69,0x76,0x65,0x2e,0x70,0x73,0x74,0x00,0x00,0x00" to type "System.Byte". Error: "Additional non-parsable characters are at the end of the string.""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the property is expecting a byte array use `[Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($data)`.  Not sure what's up with the 0x00,0x00,0x00 at the end but if you need that, just append three 0's to the end of the byte array before passing it to Set-ItemProperty.

Comment: This works, but adding the theee 0's doesn't seem to work.  I get the error: Cannot convert value "0 0" to type "System.Byte". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."   `$key = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\0a0d020000000000c000000000000046"

$data = "Z:\archive.pst"
$data = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($data)
Write-Host $data

Set-ItemProperty -path $key -name "001f0324" -value ([byte[]]($data))`

Comment: Are the trailing 0's necessary?  Try it without them.  If they are necessary, you need to add them like so `$bytes = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($data); $bytes += 0,0,0`

Comment: That did it, thanks!  Still trying to figure out this whole comment markup thing.  http://pastebin.com/FVvXg5Yj is the final code.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `Convert-ToCHexString` returns a single string with your items separated by commas.

The cast (`[byte[]]($data)`) that you perform will only work if your string contains only a single hex value or is an array of values it can parse this way. It won't split the string for you.

However, the `GetBytes` function already returns a byte array, so there's no need to convert it to a string and then back again. Also, based on your comments, it looks like outlook wants these values to be encoded as Unicode (UTF-16), which is not surprising since that's the windows default. You'll also need to null terminate your byte array (the final two 0's you see from outlook). That makes your function look like this:

```
function Convert-ToCHexString 
{
    param ([String] $str) 
    $ans = ''
    [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($str + "`0")
}
```

Comment: that's working, in a way.  Below are the values when I manually set the key in the program (Outlook) and the results from your code above.

Comment: `Outlook: "001f0324"=hex:5a,00,3a,00,5c,00,61,00,72,00,63,00,68,00,69,00,76,00,65,00,2e,00,70,00,73,00,74,00,00,00  Manually: "001f0324"=hex:5a,3a,5c,61,72,63,68,69,76,65,2e,70,73,74`  The Outlook value puts the three 0x00 at the end of the value.  Without those the value within Outlook shows up as an Asian language.

Comment: @M3THOD It looks like Outlook wants null-terminated unicode. See my update.